# SPRING - Contar o número de queries feitas em uma requisição

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data

Tenho uma simples requisição `GET` por exemplo, para buscar um produto pelo seu `ID`:

```java
@Autowired
    private ProdutoRepository produtos;

    @GetMapping
    public Optional<Produto> listarProduto(){

        return produtos.findById(1L);   

    }
```

Existe alguma propriedade que me permita ver o **número de queries feitas** em uma requisição?

Procurei sobre propriedades que eu poderia colocar no meu arquivo `application.properties` e só achei algumas como:

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

entre outras propriedades que não me ajudaram no caso. Sou iniciante no assunto e estou estudando sobre, tentei também ver se no **Postman** (onde testo as requisições) teria alguma configuração que me ajudasse nesse sentido, mas sem sucesso.

Comment: Número de query é relativo, pois uma query pode chamar uma subquery, nesse caso você contaria como uma ou duas? Qual é o seu objetivo?

Comment: @CayoSouza, a princípio somente as queries mais de fora. Sou iniciante no assunto e estou estudando sobre como mapear as minhas entidades e como elas se comportam nas operações. As vezes com as propriedades de log que eu achei não me ficou claro se estou aplicando os conceitos de forma 100% correta, ainda mais quando tento trabalhar com uma tabela com muitos registros no banco (o problema do n+1 do JPA, lazy e eager loading, paginações, entre outros) por exemplo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilizando Spring Boot você pode habilitar a seguinte propriedade conforme descrito na [documentação](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-metrics-hibernate):

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true
```

Com isso ao final de cada sessão será impresso no console um output parecido com isso:

```
12:19:30,318 INFO [org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener] – Session Metrics {
    24229 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    19394 nanoseconds spent releasing 1 JDBC connections;
    1064216 nanoseconds spent preparing 9 JDBC statements;
    1698842 nanoseconds spent executing 9 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    14999942 nanoseconds spent executing 1 flushes (flushing a total of 12 entities and 12 collections);
    64915 nanoseconds spent executing 1 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
```

Com isso você pode verificar que foram executados **n statements**, no meu exemplo foram 9 statements (queries), bem como o tempo gasto para as operações.

De qualquer forma, programaticamente você pode implementar um interceptor para logar isso. A `SessionFactory` possui uma interface para recuperarmos as estatísticas:

```
Statistics estatisticas = sessionFactory.getStatistics();
System.out.println(estatisticas.getQueryExecutionCount());
```

Existem várias outras opções para você logar, pode conferir nesta [documentação](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/stat/Statistics.html)

Comment: muito obrigado pela ajuda, esclareceu meus estudos!

Answer (score 1):

Infelizmente, até onde eu sei, o framework Spring e o Hibernate não oferece função nenhuma para contar as queries sendo executadas.

Seria possível ligar o query loggin, mas toda query executada iria ser registrada alí e seria demais para um arquivo de log, causando problemas. Isso porque em baixo nível onde não estamos vendo, pode ser (existem casos) que dezenas de queries estejam sendo executadas e não sabemos. Acredito que esse seja o motivo que queira saber como ver o número de queries sendo executadas.

Felizmente existe uma maneira legal de fazer isso. Você pode implementar no seu programa um Hibernate Interceptor que pode contar o número de queries por cada requisição numa aplicação Spring MVC que utiliza Hibernate e JPA.

Seria muito texto e muito código para eu colocar aqui, então vou deixar o link onde você pode ver como implementar esse serviço. 
O artigo é inglês, então se você tem problemas com o a língua, recomendo usar o google tradutor ou a função do tradutor direto do Chrome para entender melhor. 
Espero que ajude.

Aqui está o artigo: http://knes1.github.io/blog/2015/2015-07-08-counting-queries-per-request-with-hibernate-and-spring.html

Comment: Existe uma forma de logar estatísticas, isso ajuda na interpretação dos gargalos na execução de operações, de uma olhada na minha resposta.

Comment: Legal! E isso vale apenas para Spring boot ou para se eu quiser usar somente o Spring MVC, tambem?

Comment: Na realidade isso é uma configuração do Hibernate, então você pode habilitar esta flag para o Hibernate em qualquer projeto que o utilize

Comment: Massa! Muito obrigado!